# Anti virus integration with .net application

Tags: .net, antivirus

I would like to use anti virus integration with my .net application when uploading files using the application. Has any anti virus API available for .Net?

Answer (score 14):

I don't want to resurrect an old question, but I was in need of a solution that the question was asking about.  I evaluated a lot of things and came to the conclusion that there was really not one good .NET library for this.  So I made my own.

The library is called nClam, and it connects to a ClamAV server.  It is open-source (Apache License 2.0) library which has a very simple API.  You can obtain it here: https://github.com/tekmaven/nClam.  There is also a nuget package: nClam.

I hope someone who stumbles on this question in the future benefits from my library!

Comment: I am getting this issue: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3310

Comment: I responded to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31800465/139046.  Mark it as the accepted answer if it helps you :).

Answer (score 2):

Why not install the antivirus software on the receiving server?  That way you could keep the definitions updated, which may not happen on the uploading client app.

Comment: The reason is antivirus software needs some time to detect and delete the file with virus.  It is not a good way to use in file server.

Answer (score 2):

I use ClamWin on my Desktop, and it's built on the open-source Clam AntiVirus libraries: http://www.clamav.net/download/third-party-tools/3rdparty-library/

It looks like they have a couple of differing bindings for .NET:

[ClamAv#](http://clamav-sharp.sourceforge.net/)

[WRAVlib](http://www.wolfereiter.com/antivirus.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Symantec offers [Scan Engine](http://www.symantec.com/scan-engine) as a way to integrate anti-virus into your .Net application. If this is for non-commercial (in house) software, and your company already uses Symantec, then this might be a good option for you as well. I can't speak for ClamAV or nClam as I have never personally used them.

Comment: Symantec not providing the API to integrate with the application. They're offering publishing and consuming the customer API. I couldn't understand their API Management. Anybody can guide?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you a nuget called anti-virus scanner, with that you can do it with ease https://www.nuget.org/packages/AntiVirusScanner/
This nuget basically calls microsoft windows defender apis.