# Restrict a docx file from uploading which has exe embedded into it using WEB API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a docx file with an executable file embedded into it. I am using this docx file and uploading it into the application using WEB API 2. The file gets uploaded successfully. Now on downloading the file if I click on the embedded exe, the exe gets executed.

Can any one help me to prevent the docx file which has executable file embedded into it using WEB API 2.

Comment: You may want to use some file scanners which can scan the file being uploaded before it gets persistent on the server disk

Comment: But how is the file scanner interact with the file uploaded process here.  The file upload process is handled by the WEB API controller method which is not at all linked with the file scanner. Can you please help me to know more details on this.

Comment: This may help you to understand [Scanning files before uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520499/run-a-virus-scan-while-uploading-files-in-asp-net)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. I am looking into them.