# Check for Viruses before uploading Amazon S3?

Tags: java, api, amazon-s3

How can I check files before uploading to **Amazon S3**,any tips?

**Updated:**
It need for my web-site when users upload a file i want to check whether it's not infected. 
Is there any API which allows for check files programmatically ?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Does the virus scanner on your machine check outgoing files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution is [@Joe's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57135/joe) answer to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975112/net-virus-scanning-api/975156#975156) for c#:

> I would probably just make a system call to run an independent process to do the scan. 
>   There are a number of command-line AV engines out there from various vendors.

Comment: just for google: one of the best command line free anti-viruses is clamAV multi platform so you can work with any OS, and use Any programming lang that can execute system applications, php, java, c# most high level programming langs

Answer (score 3):

If you mean manually: try the online virusscanner at http://www.virustotal.com/ - It checks against a lot of antivirus programs for you.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out https://scanii.com - it's an API for malware detection with pre-built clients in many languages that integrates with S3 directly (and without code changes if you are using AWS lambda) - I work on scanii so this is a bit of self promotion :)

As an added bonus, scanii can detect a lot more than just malware such as NSFW images and language.