# Antivirus API for scanning before saving to file server

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, antivirus, antivirus-integration

Is their an API for Kaspersky to scan for virus when uploading files to an file server from an ASP .NET Application.My requirement is that before the saving is done the file must be checked for virus.Is it possible to scan for virus before saving the file .

Comment: saved it somewhere temporary that web users can not use it, then run a command line to virus check it, then move it to the final position.

Comment: This post can help you:   http://stackoverflow.com/a/35684198/1442180

Answer (score 4):

Kaspersky has a SDK but it seems you will have to contact them to receive any documentation: [Antivirus SDK](http://www.kaspersky.com/partners/oem/oem-technology-solutions/anti-virus_SDK)

Many web applications use `ClamAV` in daemon (service) mode for these purposes. A plus is that `ClamAV` is free of charge.

- [Here](https://github.com/michaelhans/Clamson/) you can find a library for .NET that talks with `ClamAV`.

Comment: Clamson appears to be abandoned, what appears to be a modern package is nClam https://github.com/tekmaven/nClam

Comment: G DATA has an easy to use API with SDKs in many programming languages: https://www.gdatasoftware.com/oem/verdict-as-a-service