# How to handle malicious JS when allowing users to upload their own JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, security

We have a website that allows users to upload their own JavaScript which gets loaded with the site's pages. Problem is if user adds a malicious script (eg. keylogger). Can anyone give any idea(s) on how to handle this?

Comment: web programming best practice: never trust the user - well, you could whip an anti virus into your application stack to check whether the js is malicious or not..

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765017/check-upload-file-for-virus-in-mvc3) might help you. But as far as i know an antivirus can't detect a Javascript keylogger.

Comment: It is hard to tell submitted JS by users are legitimate or malicious scripts, just in case to get rid of XSS you can use `append` or `prepend` method together with custom function for filtering uploaded data.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, you are creating an attacker's playground!  If you let the user (attacker) upload his own JavaScript, then there are so many malicious things he can do.

I disagree with the people who are talking about scanning the JavaScript for viruses.  Anti-virus software searches for known bad signatures in software and mainly targets malicious software that has affected a large number of people.  Remember: each signature that an anti-virus software checks against was the result of many man hours worth of analysis of a known threat.  It does not detect zero-day threats!  When you let a user write his own JavaScript, he is not limited to these known bad signatures.  He can do whatever he wants, and there is no way that anti-virus software can tell if what is happening is malicious or intended by business logic.

Let's start to illustrate some concerns if you allow a user (= attacker) to upload his own JavaScript:

- Unless you put httpOnly on all of your cookies, attacker can read them.  For example, he may be able to hijack sessions.
- Attacker can read keyboard and mouse events.  For example, he may be able to steal user passwords.
- How do you prevent cross-site-request-forgery?  By letting attacker upload his own JavaScript, he can bypass your protection and perform any action he wants.  For example, he could create a DoS attack that makes every user upload content of his choice.  Then, whenever somebody comes to your server, it takes forever to load a page because there is too much JavaScript to download before anything can happen.
- Attacker can read anybody else's DOM and send it to anywhere.  If there is anything private or sensitive in the DOM, attacker has it.
- Attacker can DoS any other user with alerts or various other methods.

If you want, you can play the cat-and-mouse game: you propose a way to prevent the issues I mention above, then I tell you how the attacker can bypass it, then you alter your solution, then I alter my attack, and so on.  You might be able to prevent some things, but you won't be able to prevent all of the attacks.  Security is hard!

Bottom line: don't do it!