# Virus / Spam Scanner Programatically for .NET?

Tags: .net, antivirus, email-spam, spam-prevention

I am writing a piece of messaging software that will send and receive text, voice, fax etc. via SMTP (email).

I need to Programatically have the ability to scan incoming and outgoing emails for viruses, spam etc.

**QUESTION: Can anyone offer a suggestion on a product to use for this? I tend to stay away from the consumer level software (Symantec, Mcaffe etc.)**

My software is all C#/C++ so it would be ideal if it has a .NET interface, but if it is a "C" that should work too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the related questions on the right help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975112/net-virus-scanning-api http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194013/anti-virus-integration-with-net-application

Comment: @weiqure: That tells him how to do it, but doesn't tell him which product to use, which is his question.

Answer (score 0):

[Dspam](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/dspam/index.php?title=Main_Page) might be just what you're looking for. Otherwise, [this simple C# class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9008385/20595) that integrates with SpamAssassin might be helpful.