# spamassassin check score C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, spam-prevention, spamassassin

Is there a way to check the score in an ASP.Net application? A class or something similar for .Net? How about other Spam Filters out there.
--Edited
I am looking for a way to check the spam score of the email messages in C#.

Comment: Check what score? You might be more detailed about what you are trying to do. http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Ridvan, do you want to implememt a system which gets the emails from the server and checks what is spam and what is good? if so, what do you want to do with good and bad messages?

Comment: I am trying to implement a tool that would check the spam score of of an email message if From, Subject and Body is provided. Not when I receive the email, but before an email it is sent, or a web tool to show the spam score of an email. I have seen this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/BayesianCS.aspx but to me  it is not really Spam Assasin

Comment: There's [MailingCheck](http://www.mailingcheck.com/download-spam-checker/) which does just that as a quick desktop app. If you want programattic use I think you might have to run spamassassin as a service and use its service interface to query the score.

Comment: Postmark now [host a JSON web service](http://spamcheck.postmarkapp.com/) you can use too

Answer (score 6):

Here is my super simplified "just check the score" code for connecting to a running Spam Assassin email check from C# which I wrote for http://elasticemail.com. Just setup SA to run on a server and set the access permissions.

Then you can use this code to call it:

```
public class SimpleSpamAssassin
{
    public class RuleResult
    {
        public double Score = 0;
        public string Rule = "";
        public string Description = "";

        public RuleResult() { }
        public RuleResult(string line)
        {
            Score = double.Parse(line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(" ")).Trim());
            line = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(" ") + 1);
            Rule = line.Substring(0, 23).Trim();
            Description = line.Substring(23).Trim();
        }
    }
    public static List<RuleResult> GetReport(string serverIP, string message) 
    {
        string command = "REPORT";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("{0} SPAMC/1.2\r\n", command);
        sb.AppendFormat("Content-Length: {0}\r\n\r\n", message.Length);
        sb.AppendFormat(message);

        byte[] messageBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString());

        using (Socket spamAssassinSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
        {
            spamAssassinSocket.Connect(serverIP, 783);
            spamAssassinSocket.Send(messageBuffer);
            spamAssassinSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);

            int received;
            string receivedMessage = string.Empty;
            do
            {
                byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[1024];
                received = spamAssassinSocket.Receive(receiveBuffer);
                receivedMessage += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBuffer, 0, received);
            }
            while (received > 0);

            spamAssassinSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);

            return ParseResponse(receivedMessage);
        }

    }

    private static List<RuleResult> ParseResponse(string receivedMessage)
    {
        //merge line endings
        receivedMessage = receivedMessage.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
        receivedMessage = receivedMessage.Replace("\r", "\n");
        string[] lines = receivedMessage.Split('\n');

        List<RuleResult> results = new List<RuleResult>();
        bool inReport = false;
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (inReport)
            {
                try
                {
                    results.Add(new RuleResult(line.Trim()));
                }
                catch
                {
                    //past the end of the report
                }
            }

            if (line.StartsWith("---"))
                inReport = true;
        }

        return results;
    }

}
```

Usage is quite easy:

```
List<RuleResult> spamCheckResult = SimpleSpamAssassin.GetReport(IP OF SA Server, FULL Email including headers);
```

It will return the list of spam check rules you hit and the resulting score impact.

Comment: Getting error on  spamAssassinSocket.Receive(receiveBuffer) "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure if that's what you are searching for, but there is a C# wrapper that simplifies the communication with a SpamAssassin server on Code Project:

- [A C# Wrapper for the SpamAssassin Protocol](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ZetaSpamAssassin.aspx)

Hope that helps!